# Change key name in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I am checking the attributes in a JavaScript object, replacing some of the keys by deleting the prefix "element" and saving the new values in another object.

```
var keys = Object.keys(json);
for (var j=0; j < keys.length; j++) {
   key = keys[j].replace("element_", "");
   switch(key) {
   default :
      tmp[key] = json[key];
      break;
   }
}
```

The matter is that when I do that, I can log all the keys, they have the correct names, but when I try to set the values associated to these keys, they are undefined (json[key]).

Is that due to the fact that I converted the keys (`Objects`) to `Strings` (with the `replace` method)?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `switch` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are looking for the property in the original object using the new key. Use `keys[j]` instead of `key`:

```
var keys = Object.keys(json);
for (var j=0; j < keys.length; j++) {
   var key = keys[j].replace(/^element_/, "");
   tmp[key] = json[keys[j]];
}
```

I uses a regular expression in the replace so that `^` can match the beginning of the string. That way it only replaces the string when it is a prefix, and doesn't turn for example `noexample_data` into `no_data`.

Note: What you have is not "a json", it's a JavaScript object. JSON is a text format for representing data.

> Is that due to the fact that I converted the keys (Objects) to Strings
>   (with the replace method)?

No. The keys are strings, not objects.

---

You could also change the properties in the original object by deleting the old ones and adding new:

```
var keys = Object.keys(json);
for (var j=0; j < keys.length; j++) {
   if (keys[j].indexOf("element_") == 0) {
     json[keys[j].substr(8)] = json[keys[j]];
     delete json[keys[j]];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 34):

We'll write a little function to fix the key the way you want.

```
function fix_key(key) { return key.replace(/^element_/, ''); }
```

#### Underscore

```
_.object(
  _.map(_.keys(json), fix_key),
  _.values(json)
)
```

#### ES5/loop

```
var keys = Object.keys(json);
var result = {};

for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  var key = keys[i];
  result[fix_key(key)] = json[key];
}

return result;
```

#### ES5/reduce

```
Object.keys(json) . reduce(function(result, key) {
  result[fix_key(key)] = json[key];
  return result;
}, {});
```

#### ES6

```
Object.assign(
  {},
  ...Object.keys(json) .
    map(key => ({[fix_key(key)]: json[key]}))
)
```

This makes an array of little objects each with one key-value pair, using the ES6 "computed property name" feature, then passes them to `Object.assign` using the ES6 "spread" operator, which merges them together.

Comment: Why do we need to add the most outer parentheses here: ```({[fix_key(key)]: json[key]})``` ? thanks

Comment: Because otherwise the curly bracket would be taken as the beginning of a JS code block, instead of the beginning of an object literal.

Comment: I see. How does it work then, is it just applying the parentheses priority in code execution?

Comment: The parentheses have no effect on semantics, just as  `2` is identical to `(2)`. In this case, they merely enclose an object literal. The effect is the same as writing `({a: 1})` anywhere.

Comment: Fantastic. The ES6 solution is super elegant. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var keys = Object.keys(json);
for (var j=0; j < keys.length; j++) {
   var key = keys[j]; // key
   var value = json[key]; // data
   delete json[key]; // deleting data with old key
   key = key.replace("element_", ""); // renaming key
   json[key] = value; // setting data with new key
}
```

or extend prototype of Object

```
Object.prototype.renameKey = function (oldName, newName) {
    if (!newName) return this;
    if (oldName === newName) return this;

    if (this.hasOwnProperty(oldName)) {
        this[newName] = this[oldName];
        delete this[oldName];
    }
    return this;
};

var keys = Object.keys(json);
keys.forEach(function(key) { json.renameKey(key, key.replace('element_', ''); });
```

Answer (score 3):

### ES2019

```
Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(json).map(([k,v]) => [k.replace('element_', ''), v])
);
```

Answer (score 2):

`key` is not original `json` because you have remove `element_` prefix

```
var keys = Object.keys(json);
for (var j=0; j < keys.length; j++) {
   key = keys[j].replace("element_", "");
   var _key = keys[j];
   switch(key) {
   default :
      tmp[key] = json[_key];
      break;
   }
}
```