# Javascript library to map between objects?

Tags: javascript

I always seem to have this issue where I need to map between a source and destination's object layout.

E.g.

My form might have data such as

```
{
  field1: 123,
  field2: "test"
}
```

but my API will expect data to be:

```
{
   apiCol1: 123,
   apiCol2: "test"
}
```

Obviously, you can do this manually every time. However, instead of reinventing the wheel, is there a native JS tool or JS library to map between two different object schema's given a field map?

Comment: why not change the form? btw, asking for library is ot on so.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32452014/change-key-name-in-javascript-object

Comment: you are just looking to rename the keys?

Comment: @NinaScholz Know a place where I can?

Comment: @hackerrdave Yes and no, looking to create a new object with new keys with same values

Comment: You don't even need a library. You can use a key-to-key map and `Object.keys` and `array.reduce` for this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function for that, like this

```js
var schema = {
  field1: 'apiCol1',
  field2: 'apiCol2',
};

function map(schema, obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, k) => {
    a[schema[k]] = obj[k];
    return a;
  }, {});
}

var result = map(schema, {
  field1: 123,
  field2: "test"
});

console.log(result);
```